# how to prevent zooming of parantView while zooming of imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

i have created CustomeView that contain Scroll-view.inside scroll view there is one container view that contain image view plus two button(Okay and cancel).

Following is my view-hierarchy.
CustomeView -> ScrollView -> ContainerView -> (imageView + OtherComponent).

There are two problem i faced.

1. while zoom in-out imageview,CustomeView is also zoomed in-out with
   respect to Scrollview.
2. other component postion is changed while zoom in-out.

   ```
   class cameraPreview : UIView , UIScrollViewDelegate {

   var selectedImage : UIImage!
   var backGroundView = UIView()
   var imageScrollview = UIScrollView()
   var metaData : [String:Any]?

   let backgroundImageView  = UIImageView()
   var closeButton : UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
       button.setImage(UIImage(named:"closeWhite"), for: .normal)
       button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeClick), for: .touchUpInside)
       return button
   }()


   var okButton : UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
       button.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
       button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
       button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
       button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
       button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
       button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(okClick), for: .touchUpInside)
       return button
   }()





   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       commoninit()
   }

   required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       commoninit()
   }


   required init(image:UIImage,frame:CGRect,metaData:[String:Any]?) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       self.selectedImage = image
       self.metaData = metaData
       commoninit()
   }

   override func layoutSubviews() {


   }


   func commoninit() {

       backGroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
       backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

       self.addSubview(imageScrollview)
       imageScrollview.addSubview(backGroundView)
       backGroundView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
       backGroundView.addSubview(closeButton)
       backGroundView.addSubview(okButton)




       imageScrollview.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
           make.edges.equalTo(self)
       }
       backGroundView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                   make.edges.equalTo(imageScrollview)
                   make.height.width.equalTo(self)
       }

       backgroundImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
           make.edges.equalTo(backGroundView)
       }
       okButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
           make.width.equalTo(80)
           make.height.equalTo(30)
           make.centerX.equalTo(backGroundView.snp.centerX)
           make.bottom.equalTo(backGroundView).offset(-20)
       }



       closeButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
           make.width.height.equalTo(30)
           make.left.equalTo(20)
           make.top.equalTo(10)
       }

       backgroundImageView.image = selectedImage
       imageScrollview.delegate = self
       imageScrollview.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
       imageScrollview.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
   }


   func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
       return backgroundImageView
   }

   @objc func closeClick(sender:UIButton) {
       self.removeFromSuperview()
   }

   @objc func okClick(sender:UIButton) {
       if let topCotroller = UIApplication.shared.gettopMostViewController() {
           self.removeFromSuperview()
           let mediaDetailController = UploadDetailsViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Upload)
           mediaDetailController.mediaImage = selectedImage
           if metaData != nil {
               mediaDetailController.exifDictionary = metaData![kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String] as? [String : AnyObject]
           }
           topCotroller.navigationController?.pushViewController(mediaDetailController, animated: true)
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Following is code to add cameraPreview inside current ControllerView

```
let imagePreview = cameraPreview(image: image, frame: UIScreen.main.bounds,metaData:metaData)
         self.view.addSubview(imagePreview)
```

Answer (score 1):

your other component is zoom in-out because you put those component inside ScrollView.if you simply put those component out side of ScrollView than your component will not zoom in-out with respect to ScrollView.

Following is Source Code.

```
class cameraPreview : UIView , UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var selectedImage : UIImage!
    var backGroundView = UIView()
    var imageScrollview = UIScrollView()
    var metaData : [String:Any]?

    let backgroundImageView  = UIImageView()
    var closeButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named:"closeWhite"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()


    var okButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("OK", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(okClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()





    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commoninit()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commoninit()
    }


    required init(image:UIImage,frame:CGRect,metaData:[String:Any]?) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.selectedImage = image
        self.metaData = metaData
        commoninit()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {


    }


    func commoninit() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        backGroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        self.addSubview(imageScrollview)
        imageScrollview.addSubview(backGroundView)
        backGroundView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        self.addSubview(closeButton)
        self.addSubview(okButton)




        imageScrollview.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
        }
        backGroundView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(imageScrollview)
            make.height.width.equalTo(self)
        }

        backgroundImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(backGroundView)
        }
        okButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.equalTo(80)
            make.height.equalTo(30)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self).offset(-20)
        }



        closeButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.height.equalTo(30)
            make.left.equalTo(20)
            make.top.equalTo(10)
        }

        backgroundImageView.image = selectedImage
        imageScrollview.delegate = self
        imageScrollview.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        imageScrollview.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    }


    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return backgroundImageView
    }

    @objc func closeClick(sender:UIButton) {
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @objc func okClick(sender:UIButton) {
        if let topCotroller = UIApplication.shared.gettopMostViewController() {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
            let mediaDetailController = UploadDetailsViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .Upload)
            mediaDetailController.mediaImage = selectedImage
            if metaData != nil {
                mediaDetailController.exifDictionary = metaData![kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String] as? [String : AnyObject]
            }
            topCotroller.navigationController?.pushViewController(mediaDetailController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```